# How to build thrift with llvm-link

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, thrift

I'm building thrift pulled from Github with clang.
I set cmake options.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBOOST_ROOT=[The path to boost] -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" -DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS="-lc++ -lc++abi -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" ../
```

and ran "make".

```
make -j3
```

However, "make" used "ld" instead of llvm-link, so linking errors occured.
Then, I added options as follows to "cmake" ones.

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE=llvm-link and -DCMAKE_LINKER=llvm-link
```

and retrid "cmake" and "make", but llvm-link didn't run well.

```
llvm-link: Not enough positional command line arguments specified!
```

Any idea for this?

Comment: Seems to me that you need to add more command line parameters to your linker...since this llvm thing is new to me, I can't help much, maybe reading some manuals, can give you more details about what are you missing.

Comment: The [CMake support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2850) has been introduced just recently into the project. Maybe [the mailing list](http://thrift.apache.org/mailing) is a better place to discuss this.